Error from token exchange: Runtime call was blocked because connection has error status: Enabled| Error, and sharepointonline is in the block list
I encountered an error while patching data in SharePoint using Power Automate. Does anyone know the cause or solution for this issue? Please help.
"status": 401,
"source": "https://unitedstates-002.token.azure-apim.net:443/tokens/unitedstates-002/sharepointonline/1e42c429246940348c2c2f921babcd77/exchange",
"message": "Error from token exchange: Runtime call was blocked because connection has error status: Enabled| Error, and sharepointonline is in the block list. Connection errors: [ParameterName: token, Error: Code: Unauthorized, Message: 'Failed to refresh access token for service: sharepointonlinecertificatev2. Correlation Id=cb83fd44-520e-46ea-88b2-38922d9c5144, UTC TimeStamp=10/8/2024 4:01:22 PM, Error: Failed to acquire token from AAD: {\"error\":\"invalid_grant\",\"error_description\":\"AADSTS700082: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity. The token was issued on 2024-06-20T14:19:31.5093139Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00. Trace ID: 9d5ea7b4-4c20-4c25-a673-0cae368c7400 Correlation ID: 819d6256-3dea-4a10-b3b3-7c5e1fe0b6cf Timestamp: 2024-10-08 16:01:22Z\",\"error_codes\":[700082],\"timestamp\":\"2024-10-08 16:01:22Z\",\"trace_id\":\"9d5ea7b4-4c20-4c25-a673-0cae368c7400\",\"correlation_id\":\"819d6256-3dea-4a10-b3b3-7c5e1fe0b6cf\",\"error_uri\":\"https://login.windows.net/error?code=700082\"}']"

I need to patch data from Power Apps to SharePoint using Power Automate, but I encountered an error. Error from token exchange: Runtime call was blocked because connection has error status: Enabled| Error, and sharepointonline is in the block list.

In my experience, connecting Power Apps to Power Automate flows always ends up breaking my connections.
I would recommend going into your Power App, navigate to the Data tab, remove all your connections, then readd all your connections. It might be worth going into your Power Automate flow and checking the connection reference of each step and ensuring those are correct as well.
Here are a few references that support my suspicion:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/error-from-token-exchange-runtime-call-was-blocked-because/td-p/2071789
https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=ee803915-a210-45b7-8661-f263c1791f18
https://community.powerplatform.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=d6e1f462-13bd-4005-97b7-083665ef7302

Please let me know if this solves your problem.
